# Is there a language in Python that can be used to implement logical data cuts?

Tags: python, logic

Let's say I have some data in the following form:

```
variable1 = [23, 20, 13, 24, 25, 28, 26, 17, 18, 29]
variable2 = [37, 46, 41, 40, 40, 39, 43, 42, 45, 56]
variable3 = [101, 120, 110, 140]
```

Now let's say I want to apply some data cuts. Maybe I could have a cut requirement something like the following:

- I require all values of `variable1` to be greater than or equal to 20.
- I require all values of `variable2` to be greater than or equal to 40 and less than or equal to 45.
- If some values of `variable1` have passed the cut, then `variable3` has no cut applied.
- If some values of `variable1` have not passed the cut, then I require all values of `variable3` to be greater than 115.

Is there some languaguage that could be used in Python to compactly describe these logical data cuts, which then could be applied? I could envisage something a bit like the following:

```
data = DataClass(variables = [variable1, variable2, variable3])
data.applyCut(cut = "variable1 >=20; 40 <= variable2 <= 45")
data.applyCut(cut = "if no variable1 then variable3 > 115")
data.print()
```

I know that this cut logic could be implemented in a way such as the following:

```
>>> variable1 = [23, 20, 13, 24, 25, 28, 26, 17, 18, 29]
>>> variable2 = [37, 46, 41, 40, 40, 39, 43, 42, 45, 56]
>>> variable3 = [101, 120, 110, 140]
>>> variable1 = [value for value in variable1 if value >= 20]
>>> variable2 = [value for value in variable2 if (value >= 40) and (value <=45)]
>>> print(variable1)
[23, 20, 24, 25, 28, 26, 29]
>>> print(variable2)
[41, 40, 40, 43, 42, 45]
>>> if not variable1:
...     variable3 = [value for value in variable3 if value > 115]
... else:
...     variable3 = [value for value in variable3]
... 
>>> print(variable3)
[101, 120, 110, 140]
```

What I'm looking for is a compact language in Python for doing this and similar types of data manipulation, perhaps using strings for cut specifications and methods of special data classes to apply the cuts.

Comment: How do the list comprehensions you provide fail to meet your needs?

Comment: you might look towards languages that are more geared towards DSL writing such as Haskell or Scala for this.

Comment: If e.g. `variable1` was a `numpy.ndarray`, `variable1[variable1>=20]` would give you `array([23, 20, 24, 25, 28, 26, 29])`.

Comment: I'm with @FredLarson on this. Now, if you're going to be dealing with numerical data, you probably want to use NumPy!

Comment: NumPy indeed, and perhaps even Pandas (which can almost behave like [SQL for numpy data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)),

Comment: You can chain comparisions in Python: `40 <= value <= 45`.

Comment: also, take a look at `any()` and `all()`.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your suggestions. NumPy is well suited to my purposes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think numpy might be what you want:

```
import numpy as np
v1 = np.array([23, 20, 13, 24, 25, 28, 26, 17, 18, 29])
v2 = np.array([37, 46, 41, 40, 40, 39, 43, 42, 45, 56])
v3 = np.array([101, 120, 110, 140])

def myfilter(v1, v2, v3): # how I would parse your "DataClass" code
    valid_ixs = (v1 >= 20) & (v2 >= 40) & (v2 <= 45)
    if any(valid_ixs): # could also use valid_ixs.sum()
        return v3[v3 > 115]
    return v3
print(myfilter(v1, v2, v3))

# what you're doing in python
v1 = v1[v1 >= 20]
v2 = v2[(v2 >= 40) & (v2 <= 45)]
v3 = v3[v3 > 115] if v1 else v3
```

Note that, in python, `5 <= x <= 10` translates to `5 <= x and x <= 10`, when, for numpy, you need `&` instead of `and` (because of operator overloading rules, if you're curious).

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you very much for your suggestions. The three key lines are so short and concise. It's NumPy for me then!